# PHP Error when check if URL Query = equals to

Tags: php, url

I get an error when I try to check if a query taken from the url equals something.

Error: **syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL, expecting ',' or ')'**

```
if (isset($_GET['lang'] == 'eng')) {
    echo 'ENG';
}else if (isset($_GET['lang'] == 'alb')) {
    echo 'ALB';
}else {
    echo 'MKD';
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `==` and `isset` to gether:

```
if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang']=='eng') {
    echo 'ENG';
}
else if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'alb') {
    echo 'ALB';
}else {
    echo 'MKD';
}
```

Comment: Additionally, PHP uses "elseif" not "else if"

Comment: I am getting an error, **syntax error, unexpected ')'**, in the first line. What is causing that?

Comment: @Boris: Try to use above code. Let us know if there is any problem with that.

Comment: @Ronak Ah, you can.  I was thinking of the limitation if you don't use curly braces. My bad :)  Boris, The syntax error is because the isset should be closed before the && and there is an extra ) at the end of the if

Comment: @RonakPatel I copied and pasted the code above. Thats the error I get...

Comment: @Boris: Oh.  sorry.. There was 1 extra closing bracket.. Now try it